# TableLayoutPanel constructing an object for each cell

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

Hi I am working on a c# Windows Form design assignment. Basically we have been supplied with most of the code to create a working board game similar to snakes and ladders.
So far I have created a TableLayoutPanel to act as the gui for board.
Next is the part I'm stuck at. I have to display all the squares. In the project they have supplied a SquareControl class that has the background colour and font of each square but I have no idea how to add these objects to my TableLayoutPanel

edit: this is the code for the style of square
  public SquareControl(Square square, BindingList players) {

```
        this.square = square;
        this.players = players;

        //  Set GUI properties of the whole square.
        Size = new Size(SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE);
        Margin = new Padding(0);  // No spacing around the cell. (Default is 3 pixels.)
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;

        LoadImageWhenNeeded();
        SetTextColour();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try following link. I think It will help u.

http://www.dotnetpools.com/Article/ArticleDetiail/?articleId=131